# System property used in camel for velocity template uses default value, not environment-level setting

Tags: java, spring, properties, apache-camel

I'm using Spring and Camel for a small service. Both are drawing on several locations for properties files, including environment-specific settings file specified on the server launch config.

Spring:

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath*:config/*.properties,classpath:config/*.properties, file:${application.properties.file}"/>
```

Camel context:

```
<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:config/camel-constant.properties,
            config/application.properties, file:${application.properties.file}"/>
```

this seems to be fine for eg endpoint configuration:

```
<endpoint id="supplierEmail" uri="smtp:${mailsender.host}?contentType=text/html"/>
```

But I want to access a property in my velocity template. If I try eg

```
<setHeader headerName="environment_id">
    <simple>${properties:environment.id}</simple>
</setHeader>
```

$headers.environment_id in velocity template picks up a value, but it's the default value, not the value from the environment-level properties file.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, ignore. Config was pointing at the wrong flipping file.